# Position of tag in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to get the position of tag in form? (tag -> input, select, radio etc.) I am making a form dynamically. The user can create a from that will be shown to the client (he won't write the code just select the tags). For that I need position of the tags inside the form to place them accordingly.

Example:

```
input 1
checkbox 1
select 1
input 2
radio 1
checkbox 2
```

The input 2 is on 4th position. ?

Comment: Please also explain what you need this for.

Comment: If there are no other elements in your form then jquery index would give you that (`.index()` on the element), see https://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: The form contains other elements like divs.

Comment: Your question is a little too broad, and there is no sample markup or any kind of JS to boot. Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: In jQuery doc search on `.index()`

Comment: Everyone I don't know why I get this -ve on my question. What I just wanted was to get the index of input tags. If there is some function I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this, plain JS:

```
var form = document.getElementById('form_id');
var tagType = 'input';
var tagId = 'input_2';

var l = form.children.length;

for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    if (form.children[i].nodeName.toLowerCase() == tagType && form.children[i].id == tagId) {
        console.log('Position:' + i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP has jQuery available.

Comment: I prefer vanilla JS, more performant if a bit more verbose. :)

Comment: Isn't this hard-coding? The input tags might be more. And will this work if there are divs too inside the form? I want that only the form tags like input, select, radio etc should be considered!

Comment: @Shaggy Well the if statement checks if the tag is an input and if it has a certain ID, so you can have multiple input tags, you just put an incremental id on every input, this is just an example, you can put variables instead of `'input'` and `'input_2'` to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There are some jQuery methods to get the index, but as we have some select drop down in middle it wont work as expected(if we have all input tags the it will work). I have given example below check it. So best way to do it is add a data attribute to every element and use jquery to get it. Its not dynamic but it will work for you.

```js
function test(){
  var element = document.getElementById( "input2" );
  alert( "Basedon Input tags Index: " + ($( "input" ).index( element )+ 1) );
  alert( "Based on data attrbiute index is: "+$( element ).data("index"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input data-index="1" id="input1" placeholder="input1" type="text"/><br/><br/>
<input data-index="2" id="checkbox1" placeholder="input1" type="text"/><br/><br/>
<select data-index="3" id="select1">
<option>
select
</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<input data-index="4" id="input2" placeholder="input1" type="text"/><br/><br/>
<input data-index="5" id="radio1" placeholder="input1" type="text"/><br/><br/>
<input data-index="6" id="checkbox2" placeholder="input1" type="text"/><br/><br/>
<input data-index="7" type="button" value="getIndex" onClick="test()"/>
</form>
```